# ng2-smart-table display list of object

Tags: angularjs, ng2-smart-table

Is there a way to display a list of objects in a single table cell for ng2-smart-table? I have tried creating a renderComponent but I am getting an empty value. Another question is will the filtering and sorting still work for this?

[image: Object that I want to dislay]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show me what is your expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood , You have a object and you want to display that data in `ng2-smart-table`.

For that follow this step.

```
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';

source : any =  LocalDataSource;
```

When you call API then you have to set that data in source.

```
this.apiService.POST({}, 'getProductList').subscribe((res) => {      
  console.log(res);                  
  this.source = new LocalDataSource(res.data);  // Set response as per your res.             
});
```

[image: Data in table]

As you can see I have also set one array and that array has objects of data and I have set in table.

I hope this may help you. :)

Comment: My problem is when there is nested list of object withing the list.
For example,

Comment: @ChongWeTan ok and I have  set code as per your image.

Comment: @ChongWeTan Please provide accurate json.

Comment: My problem is when there is a nested list of object.
For example,
{
cgst: 5,
company_id: 1,
product:[{
    product_id: 1,
    product_name: "Laptop"
    },{
    product_id: 2,
    product_name: "PC"
    }]
}

Comment: @ChongWeTan As I have add comment in answer set res per your res. In your given example, You have to just set `this.source = new LocalDataSource(res.data.product)`

Comment: Can you try this data:
 { cgst: 5, company_id: 1, product:[{ product_id: 1, product_name: "Laptop" },{ product_id: 2, product_name: "PC" }] }

Comment: @ChongWeTan Do you want to show the data cgst and company_id also in table ?

Comment: Yes, for example, the table header will be cgst, company id, product id, product name, then the content will be the corresponding, 5, 1, 1 and 2(same row), Laptop and PC (same row)

Comment: @ChongWeTan You can set object data in variable. Which you get on chage event also. For that you don't need to display in table. For example in object you can set 10 data but in page you can show only required data. :)

Comment: @ChongWeTan Hi , Can you please update your status ?